# Is there something equivalent to C's #include in Octave?

Tags: octave

Suppose that I have 2 scripts:

magic_function.m:

```
function retval = magic(x)
    retval = 12345678;
endfunction
```

other_script.m

```
#some code
X = magic(17)
```

What should I add to other_script.m in order to make function "magic" visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the documentation of [Functions and Script Files](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/octave/octave_12.html#SEC95), it should be sufficient to put the function in a file named `magic.m` in a directory specified in `LOADPATH`.

> When Octave encounters an identifier that is undefined, it first looks
>   for variables or functions that are already compiled and currently
>   listed in its symbol table. If it fails to find a definition there, it
>   searches the list of directories specified by the built-in variable
>   LOADPATH for *files ending in `.m' that have the same base name as the
>   undefined identifier.*(4) Once Octave finds a file with a name that matches, the contents of the file are read. *If it defines a single
>   function, it is compiled and executed.*

Comment: With `addpath` a path can be added to the `LOADPATH` variable.